# "Run-time error 1004, Unable to get Match Property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Tags: excel, vba, userform

[image]I am trying to get both of the `comboboxes(valuerFirmCB, valuerNameCB)` to be dynamic i.e the `valuerNameCB` will only display the names accordingly to the firm.

It works but however I got an error after adding the entry to the spreadsheet `"Run-time error 1004, Unable to get Match Property of the WorksheetFunction class"`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valuer_Details")

Dim i As Integer

Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear
For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
Me.valuerFirmCB.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value

Next i
End Sub

Private Sub valuerFirmCB_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Valuer_Details")
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(valuerFirmCB.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)

Me.valuerNameCB.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
    Me.valuerNameCB.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This error is raised when no match is found using `WorksheetFunction.Match`. Can you confirm that `valuerFirmCB.Value` returns the correct value just before that line?

Comment: yup it does return the correct value

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot replicate the error with some quick testing. The value you tried to match is somehow not found.

Comment: What types of values do you have in rows and columns?

Comment: column A:J consist of name of the firm in row 1, names of the valuers in row 2 to 20

Comment: Can you then tell after what action an error is thrown? I was able to replicate this error when I used numbers in first row. The argument passed to Match function `valuerFirmCB.Value` was of type String (as this is the return type of ComboBox) and value in the row was of type Integer. That generated an error described, which is easily handled by implicit conversion. Maybe, a screenshot of sample data will also help to understand the issue.

Comment: Now, with a screenshot, all is quite clear. Let me post an answer.

Comment: The very first comment, I asked if you could confirm if `valuerFirmCB.Value` returns the correct value, which you said it did. I guess it didn't =). @VitaliyPrushak got a good explaination below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you activate your UserForm - you trigger an UserForm_Activate event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
```

Which clears you ComboBox:

```
Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear
```

This action in its turn triggers a ComboBox_Change event if the form was hidden and a ComboBox has some value selected before activation:

```
Private Sub valuerFirmCB_Change()
```

And sets the `valuerFirmCB.Value` to `""` (Nothing, as you see on your screenshot).

As your `Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear` is a ComboBox_Change event, so event is fired and trying to find the `""` value, which generates an error in match function. Also, this error will be thrown if you simply delete the selected value from `valuerFirmCB` manually.

The way you can deal this issue is to add a simple check to `Private Sub valuerFirmCB_Change()` like this:

```
If Not valuerFirmCB.Value = "" Then
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(valuerFirmCB.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)

    Me.valuerNameCB.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
        Me.valuerNameCB.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value

    Next i
End If
```

So the search will be performed only when `valuerNameCB` has some value.

**Added per comment**

I've replicated this situation with additional buttons with code `Form.Show 0` on the worksheet and `Form.Hide` on the form. Switching between form and sheet does nothing, but if you select an item in ComboBox, Hide the form and Show again - the change event on `Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear` will be triggered. However, this won't happen if I use `Unload Me` instead of `Form.Hide`.

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this? I did, and `Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear` did not raise an change event as the combobox is clear already upon opening the userform. It would be a logical explaination though if OP could confirm that he set a rowsource for this combobox in properties.

Comment: I've replicated it with additional buttons to `Form.Show 0` on the worksheet and  `Form.Hide` on the form. Switching between form and sheet does nothing, but if you select an item in ComboBox, Hide the form and Show again - the change event on `Me.valuerFirmCB.Clear` is triggered. The `Unload Me` and `Form.Show` doesn't raise this error.

Comment: Upvoted. Since really it would be the only logical explaination possible =)

Comment: The most simpler way to get this error was just to delete a selected value from ComboBox :D